# First releasing iPhone only, later universal

Tags: ios, universal-binary

I' m working on an iOS app. I would like to release it first as a iPhone only app, and later (in a couple of months) update it to a universal app. I has to be the same app-id because it is a free game with in-app purchases.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's not a problem at all, you'd just have to write additional code to support the iPad and submit it as a regular update to your iPhone app (which then becomes a Universal app).

When the iPad originally came out, a lot of iPhone apps did exactly that.